# How to verify Metaplex storefront creators split?

Tags: solana, storefront, metaplex

[image: Unverified]

I have created NFT using Solana/Metaplex storefront on Mainnnet. The issue is we cannot find how to verify other creators wallet addresses (checked Phantom wallet didn't get any information or message) and it is also not written official documentation of Metaplex [website](https://docs.metaplex.com/storefront/create)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: this [issie](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/docs/issues/175) created 17 days ago to solve this issue. it seems we can use metaboss to solve this problem with this command: metaboss sign all -k <keypair> --candy-machine-id <candy_machine_id> --v2. but it didn't work properly, so be patient and check the community every day

Comment: Thank you for the information. Unfortunately, it is not for Metaplex/Storefront I am trying to find solution now but no luck hope soon they will add on the documentation

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem on devnet. I was able to workaround this way:

- visit http://localhost:3000/#/admin
- set the toggle to **Whitelisted**
- add the creator's address private key to the phantom wallet
- disconnect your wallet and login with the other creator's addresses

You will be shown notifications on the bell icon that says "You have some pending approvals."

The explanation might not be good enough but bear with me. I'll attach two images to clarify.

#### The creator's approval

[image: Metaplex creator's approval]

#### The whitelist

[image: Whitelist only]